# reading text file in java like csv file

Tags: java, loops

I'm facing a problem with looping through the file array.

This is the code for reading:

```
public static  ArrayList<String> readData(int colNo)  {

        Scanner sca;
        try {
            sca = new Scanner(new File("txt1.txt"));
            while(sca.hasNext()) {
                String  data=sca.next();
                String[] value=data.split(",");
                System.out.println(value[colNo]);
            }
            sca.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }
```

An image showing how it will work:

[image]

And this is the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         ArrayList<String> Firstrow=readData(0);

        for( int i=0; i<Firstrow.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(Firstrow);
        }
    }
```

This is the format of the data when it reads the file:

> jon,1266$,level5
>  smith,1060$,level3
>  rony,1686$,level6

When I run the code in `main` and call the first row it must be like:

> jon
>  smith
>  rony

So, when it reaches the `for` it should stop and say about first row.

I know there is a way to fix it, like storing the read in an array, but I don't know how to do it. *(I think the reading method isn't the right way to do it.)*

I did the same thing in `Excel` and it works:

```
public static  ArrayList<String> readExcelData(int colNo)  {
        try {
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("dat.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet s=wb.getSheet(shnum);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator=s.iterator();
        rowIterator.next();
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
             String val = formatter.formatCellValue(rowIterator.next().getCell(colNo));
            list.add(val);
        }
        System.out.println("List :::"+list);
        return list;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you're trying to print the file line by line, trying using bufferedReader and readLine():

```
FileReader fr = new fileReader(“filename”); 
BufferedReaderbr = new BufferedReader(fr);
string l; 
l = br.readLine();
```

then,

```
    while((l = br.readline())(=null) {
}
```

The bufferedReader stream method readLine() returns a null when there is no more lines to read. Hopefully this helped!

Comment: no i'm trying to read row like excel code that i gave it like reading the value after the comma , in an array or something like this thins

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of my question and it works. Hope it helps others.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList < String > empname = new ArrayList < String > ();
    ArrayList < String > empsalary = new ArrayList < String > ();
    loadData(empid, empname, empsalary);

    for (int i = 0; i < empname.size(); i++) {
        //do some event here
    }

}


public static void loadData(ArrayList < String > empid, ArrayList < String > empname, ArrayList < String > empsalary) {

    try {
        File file = new File("empdata.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String tokens[] = line.split("\\|");
            empid.add(tokens[0].trim());
            empname.add(tokens[1].trim());
            empsalary.add(tokens[2].trim());

        }

        scanner.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```